# Фильтры в css

Tags: css-filters, css

Вот [тут](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) есть css фильтры. Но они работают только в хроме. Как заставить работать во всех браузерах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), то не только в хроме, а ещё в Сафари и опере т.е. на webkit'e. Можете попробовать ИЕ заставить работать через его старое свойство [-ms-filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Для FF придётся использовать SVG. Посмотреть статью на эту тему можно [тут](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur-with-CSS).